# How can I achieve fast and effective String compression in Actionscript 3?

Tags: string, performance, actionscript-3

I have an Object which stores pairs for a find and replace that I perform on up to 1500 Strings at a time.

The Object is populated with pairs using a method that will accept a String and then store this as a property with the value being an automatically assigned base 36 number, like this:

```
function addShort(long:String):void
{
    _pairs[long] = _nextShort;
}
```

`_nextShort` returns an automatically incremented value being the subject of `.toString(36)`, so running the above a few times might make `_pairs` look like this:

```
_pairs:Object = {
    "class": "0",
    "testing.objects.TestBlock": "1",
    "skin.x": "2",
    "skin.y": "3",
    ...........
    "someString": "az1"
};
```

This Object could realistically end up being really large, having over a couple hundred pairs stored.

I then have a method that will take a "long" String (which will include the Strings I've given to `addShort()` previously) and return a new String where these have been replaced with their respective short value.

The method looks like this:

```
public function shorten(long:String):String
{
    for(var i:String in _pairs)
        long = long.split(i).join(_pairs[i]);

    return long;
}
```

Nice an simple, however in my mind I foresee a massive problem in a case where I might want to "shorten" 2000+ Strings and the `_pairs` Object has at the same time has over 500 pairs.

That ends up being 1,000,000 iterations all up which obviously doesn't seem very efficient at all.

How can I improve this process significantly?

Comment: It seems like you are trying to implement a derivate of run-length encoding.  Have you thought about using rle at all?

Comment: Can't say I've heard of it - do you have more information?

Comment: Looks more like some naive kind of [LZW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch) to me.

Comment: Both of those topics (LZW & RLE) seem to fit what I want to do - are there any libraries available for this in Actionscript 3?

Comment: You do know that you can chuck data into a ByteArray and call deflate() on it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments from @kapep I realized what I needed is actually a compression library that will do this work for me.

I stumbled across an [LZW compression class within a package called Calista](http://code.google.com/p/calista/source/browse/trunk/AS3/src/calista/util/LZW.as?r=3) which works great.

I did notice that the compression was really slow, which is understandable, but if there are any suggestions for something quicker I'm open to them.

Comment: There are a number of compression algorithm which are extremely fast, and may help you in your situation, but are however available in C/C++, sometimes C# or Java, or maybe Go Language. Would that fit your need ?

Answer (score 0):

How about Regular Expressions for replacing String patterns? [Catch some code](http://snipplr.com/view/6608/).

Comment: Nice tip, through unfortunately I need to replace specific strings (not patterns) with the correct short version as the information is later unpacked by reversing the process and must be exact (it is level data).

Comment: `String.replace` works with string too, you should try and see how it performs for your code. http://www.stratulat.com/blog/replace-vs-split-and-join-performance-in-actionscript-3